# Sorting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, sorting

I have entries in Excel that are like this:

```
52173 PURCHASE USA*SNACK SODA 
52172 PURCHASE USA*SNACK SODA 
668414 PURCHASE REDBOX *DVDRESERVATION
```

I would like to sort the rows ignoring everything to the `USA*SNACK`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the text to column function in Excel to split each line into smaller chunks depending on what character you specify as the delimiter.

For example, if you use space as the delimiter, you will have something like:

A: 52173
B: PURCHASE
C: USA*SNACK
D: SODA

After splitting the contents into columns, you can then sort on the specific column of your choice.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure how to split, can you please explain that

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/split-text-into-different-cells-HA102809804.aspx This is how it is done

Comment: Sure! First, paste your data into Excel. Then, click the Data tab, and under the "Data Tools" section of the ribbon, click "Text to Columns". The wizard will display, providing you with a series of options to help split the data into columns. You will choose "Delimited" for the first option. On hte next page, you select what character will delimit the text (In your case, I think you want to use "Space"). After that, hit finish and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do is create a helper column and sort on it.  You could you put the formula `=if(C2="USA*SNACK","",C2)` then sort that column.